# Typing a constant object so that values fit a certain type

Tags: typescript

I have a Javascript object that represents a set of styles, in the shape of `Record<string, CSSProperties>`:

```js
const buttonStyles = {
  Primary: {
    color: 'green',
    fontSize: '18px',
  },
  Secondary: {
    color: 'grey',
  }
}
```

The following code raises a typechecking error:

```js
function getFontSize(btnType: keyof typeof buttonStyles): string | undefined {
  // Property 'fontSize' does not exist on type [...]
  return buttonStyles[btnType].fontSize
}

// passes typecheck
const primaryFontSize: string = buttonStyles.Primary.fontSize
```

Here is a [link to a Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgVylcBlKBPANgUwjAXhgG8AoGGABQCcBLAWwENqMAuE8imULEa9gOQBzajhxgBAGk4UAZuCipaALxyCAjAA4ADgA8pnAL7SKqHKDAATZmw5duIXvxjDRGAxUOkvpWQjDAULTgMEI4UABiCkqqABRwUGAAKhjaajAA1jgYILIwmGm58EgoYOjYeACU7NB0YEIwAD4w-pY4srRgOJZ2MAD0fVTUIGnUmC7yYIoqOAIwliB4MGAgsDi6tNAwIQU4MADaAHTHALqcolAI1GDFyGiYuBD7CcmpOCeHk9Oq3qSkAzBtIwIBAlrtgAALcwZUgWLbaOhMFhRKYxdK1ToNIiIO5lB54Q40Bg2T7RGZAA).

Now, if I explicitly type my object as a `Record<string, CSSProperties>`:

```js
const buttonStyles: Record<string, CSSProperties> = {
  ...
}
```

then I fix an error and create another:

```js
function getFontSize(btnType: keyof typeof buttonStyles): string | undefined {
  // passes typecheck
  return buttonStyles[btnType].fontSize
}

// type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
const primaryFontSize: string = buttonStyles.Primary.fontSize
```

[Link to another playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIGV0AUoHsAO0YwEAzsgN4BQytyCuANrlAPwBcypYUoA5gG4adGLnDpgALwgcuPfkIC%20VKgxDdkAIwCuYMGPRgAnozKcAShAZQAJgB5uvEHwA0aTDgJESpAHzIAXkphHGAAWzgoI05qOnomFk4Acj4oCAgQJJdhWlFxKQhkgEYADnwADyzhRWzadCsxG0jo4LiGZihk1IgjKtplZSoYbRAEYjFkPggwADExMAlpAApNMBAAFSNCTgBrHtwYZGNCA61dfRBDEzIASk5HfmQAH2QRmwgYUAgbVuQAej%20yHwcFIpDIRy2VgAFlYdsI0mBtFAQGc9AZjKZSABtVYbSEAXQAdHkFgUqIMARDCMgkg9nM9XiB3p8QN8kshgOQQLgwMgQaRgHwQHBNKYjrgqShafJnElVGINPheBEonN8tJ7jK%20IFURcrpjCaEVUZifNFhAgA).

How can I provide the type for buttonStyles so that the values are simultaneously checked for their 'theoretical' and 'actual' shape, and both checks pass?

Comment: This is a bit too much for the `satisfies` operator but a generic helper function should work... Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N75EqW), for example, meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz interesting! I'm not sure I understand all of it and I didn't think the JS code would have to change. I'll look into `satisfies` too.

Comment: Is that a "yes please write up an answer because I'm likely to accept it and I want to see an explanation" or "I need time to process this before I can say yes or no to it"?

Comment: @jcalz I need time to process this before I decide if I use the solution or not, however it is definitely a valid solution which I will accept if you post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I will do so, probably in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the main issue here is that there's no built-in way to say that you want an object literal like `{color: 'grey'}` to be given a type that explicitly mentions *missing* [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  You can easily get it to be inferred as type `{color: string}`, which is seen as assignable to `CSSProperties`, but the type `{color: string}` itself doesn't know anything about `fontSize`, so you can't index into it with `fontSize` as a key.  We know that you'd get `undefined` if you read from the `fontSize` property in the *value* `{color: 'grey'}`, but the *type* `{color: string}` makes no such guarantee.  Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible and not closed/exact, and excess properties cannot be completely prohibited:

```
const val = { color: "abc", fontSize: true };
const val2: { color: string } = val; // okay
```

What you want instead is for `{color: 'grey'}` to be interpreted as something like `{color: string; fontSize?: never}`, where `fontSize` is known to be missing. (An optional property of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) cannot have a defined value, so the only type you could read from such a property would be `undefined`.)

---

[The `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) can sometimes be used to tweak the inferred type of a value without needing any extra runtime code, but there's not a great way to do this here (especially not one that scales well with the number of keys in `CSSProperties`).

Instead, in order to get the compiler to infer the type we want, we can  introduce a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function which just returns the input at runtime, but helps the compiler to synthesize the types we care about.

Here's one way to do it:

```
const asButtonStyles = <T extends Record<keyof T, CSSProperties>>(
  t: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] &
    { [P in Exclude<keyof CSSProperties, keyof T[K]>]?: never } }
) => t;
```

Here the compiler will infer `T` from the value of `t` passed in, and the compiler [constrains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to be some object type whose properties are assignable to `CSSProperties`.  Then it will check the type `T` against the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property `T[K]` is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `{ [P in Exclude<keyof CSSProperties, keyof T[K]>]?: never }`, which gives optional `never` properties to all keys of `CSSProperties` not mentioned in the keys of `T[K]`.  And that's the type returned.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const buttonStyles = asButtonStyles({
  Primary: {
    color: 'green',
    fontSize: '18px',
  },
  Secondary: {
    color: 'grey',
  }
});
/* const buttonStyles: {
    Primary: {
        color: string;
        fontSize: string;
    } & {};
    Secondary: {
        color: string;
    } & {
        fontSize?: undefined;
    };
} */
```

You can see that `buttonStyles`'s `Primary` property is known to have `string` properties at `color` and `fontSize` (and the intersection with an empty object doesn't affect that), while the `Secondary` property is known to have a `string` property at `color`, but an optional `never` property at `fontSize` (this type, `{fontSize?: never}` is displayed as `{fontSize?: undefined}` since optional properties automatically get `undefined` as a possible property value type, at least with the normal `--strict` compiler options).  This type is strong enough to give you both behaviors you want:

```
function getFontSize(btnType: keyof typeof buttonStyles): string | undefined {
  return buttonStyles[btnType].fontSize; // okay
}

const primaryFontSize: string = buttonStyles.Primary.fontSize; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGEDKmAKMD2ADrBCFAM6oDewqqS+ANvjAPwBcq5EM4A5gG5aqOPkiYQALygcuPfkIC+wYAzDdUANwSNUAXmr0mLTgCIEAIySmANCLEQJ0zjwCuaRULUbtjAEycVEbMMJzcvGB8qIr6WjoCqAD0iaj4ANYIAJ4q3hCoCOQAQq4QEGKYEJmMFLEAPAAqqFAAHtBgACaUAEpQDDDttWlQmfhwqPV2WLgExDCkFAB8CwAUwhCBqADaANKo4KhDI2P1ALqc9TsnqABkwnRBmzh7YKgAos1IjK7tUIPDoxhsHgiCQyOQ7IcARdticFidZGAoJpYNFosAAJT6BaoCBCVRiDQWEplMAVKo1AwFYqlcqVarkZY0Oh4EAAWwQMEygTuwRMqAA5HwYFAoGB+TYeaJxFIoJx+QBGAAchGa4uEigldEwvTE7Q5XOoPIYITlQuGaroykU6KEiQAVEZ1HkiTTSXSKNy6MzeOzOZ6vQHjXzwgoeQGpY4ZWF5JEhAGYtdqJ4edq1Hq-YaA4HjKE5BFBDyE5ms3QI04ZJxXB0oHBwFB2nGvcmYnbEipgHAq0hSGJUHwoBAAGIOcvLCwQMD1TLETiQsaVYgAl0ksn09HR-OoAA+qCrP1riPaxeFEFcMBey9p5PIm3Hk+nUBOADoyzLgMp8U7UIQffrh9LnDzfhYkvN1ryfFlfUyF8RxlIA)